# css padding, float does not work in html a tag

Tags: html, css

I want the menu to be shown from left to right. But `padding` and `float` do not work in HTML. Here is my code

```css
.main-nav ul li a {
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your styling code is not correct. Here is the correct css code. You may replace with this.

```css
.main-nav ul li {
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .main-nav ul li a {
            padding-left: 15px;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Both of them are working fine. Please check again.

1. You have added padding-right instead of left which does not serve any purpose
2. You have given float left which is also not serving any purpose.

As you can see in this code changing any/both of these values work perfectly. Please check your code again or elaborate what you want to achieve with this HTML snippet